How to select top N subjects under different conditions in a pandas DataFrame?
I would like to select top N & M subjects from each parent group under various child groups with the highest scores. Here, I want to select top 2 subjects from parent_group = A with child_group = 1, parent_group = B with child_group = 1 & parent_group = C with child_group = 1. Repeat the same to select top 3 subject for child_group = 2.
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

n = 300
np.random.seed(1)
parent_groups = np.random.choice(['A','B','C'], n)
child_groups = np.random.choice([1,2], n)
scores = np.random.random(size=n)
subjects = np.random.choice(range(100, 2000), n)

df = pd.DataFrame({'subjects':subjects,
                   'parent_groups':parent_groups,
                   'child_groups':child_groups,
                   'scores':scores})
df

    subjects    parent_groups   child_groups    scores
0   559         B                 1             0.969565
1   950         A                 2             0.303878
2   400         A                 2             0.313755
3   1956        B                 2             0.226462
4   1673        B                 2             0.672335
... ... ... ... ...

I was planning to subset the df into two parts based on the child groups e.g.,
df_1 = df[df['child_groups'] == 1]
df_2 = df[df['child_groups'] == 2]
df_1


    subjects    parent_groups   child_groups    scores
0   559         B               1               0.969565
5   1299        A               1               0.778922
7   574         B               1               0.615265
9   1907        B               1               0.446100
10  549         A               1               0.968013
... ... ... ... ...

Then select top 2 subjects for each parent groups based on the highest scores. Repeat the same process for df_2, which select top 3 subjects. Finally combine these subjects with their scores, parent_groups, and child_groups information into a final dataframe. However, I don't know how to proceed this in any efficient way. Any suggestions? Thanks

You can group by child_groups and parent_groups and then apply nlargest, using the child_groups number to select either 2 or 3 largest scores values:
out = (df
    .groupby(['child_groups', 'parent_groups'], as_index=False)
    .apply(lambda g:g.nlargest(1+g['child_groups'].iloc[0], 'scores'))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

Output:
    subjects parent_groups  child_groups    scores
0       1338             A             1  0.986943
1        566             A             1  0.976481
2       1911             B             1  0.992827
3       1843             B             1  0.980412
4        820             C             1  0.993938
5        141             C             1  0.932257
6       1624             A             2  0.994365
7        962             A             2  0.928267
8        846             A             2  0.886920
9        963             B             2  0.974991
10      1819             B             2  0.921134
11      1446             B             2  0.879272
12      1900             C             2  0.999769
13       480             C             2  0.991654
14      1999             C             2  0.991451

Note that if you have a more complicated relationship between child_groups and the number of values you want to keep, it would be better to use a dictionary of those values. For example:
glen = { 1: 2, 2: 3}
out = (df
    .groupby(['child_groups', 'parent_groups'], as_index=False)
    .apply(lambda g:g.nlargest(glen[g['child_groups'].iloc[0]], 'scores'))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

The output (for this example) will be the same.

@DaCard I'm glad I could help :) I've made a bit of a hack using 1+g['child_groups'].iloc[0] for the length of the group; if you want something more complex a dict would be more appropriate e.g. glen = { 1: 2, 2: 3} and then use .nlargest(glen[g['child_groups'].iloc[0]], 'scores') instead

Here is an option using groupby.cumcount()
(df.loc[
    df.sort_values('scores',ascending=False).groupby(['parent_groups','child_groups']).cumcount().lt(df['child_groups'].map({1:2,2:3}))
    ]
    .sort_values(['child_groups','parent_groups']))

Output:
     subjects parent_groups  child_groups    scores
77       1338             A             1  0.986943
240       566             A             1  0.976481
16       1911             B             1  0.992827
188      1843             B             1  0.980412
197       820             C             1  0.993938
211       141             C             1  0.932257
86       1624             A             2  0.994365
130       846             A             2  0.886920
279       962             A             2  0.928267
36       1819             B             2  0.921134
159      1446             B             2  0.879272
213       963             B             2  0.974991
84       1999             C             2  0.991451
106      1900             C             2  0.999769
116       480             C             2  0.991654

